# Detect missing > html emacs web-mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, web-mode

Hello I am new to Emacs and I am currently using it for web development projects. I am currently using Laravel and VueJS on my development. I search online what is the best major mode for this web development tools. I found out that web-mode is good for this.

But as I code I found out that it didn't detect.That I have a missing > on my html tags.
[image]

As you can see above I have a missing > on my div. But the syntax highlighting below it is still the same.

I was using Sublime text 3 before and it has the functionality.

[image]

I wan't something like Sublime text 3. that can detect missing > and it will display different syntax highlighting below it.

I really want this functionality because I am coding html most of my works.

What is the tool that is good for this on Emacs?

EDIT:
This file is a .vue file. Which is a component file for VueJS.

Comment: Have you tried `C-c C-d d`? It should be able to find malformed HTML.

Comment: I just tried it and it says 0 errors detected

Comment: BTW. I am on a .vue file. Which is a component file for VueJS.

Comment: You can try `html-check-frag.el` available via melpa.

Comment: [`flycheck` also uses `Tidy HTML5`.](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/languages.html#html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use builit flymake plus old cli `tidy`. `tidy` is available on Mac/Linux/Windows, tested on Emacs 24.4 and Emacs 25.3:

```
(defun flymake-html-init ()
       (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                          'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
              (local-file (file-relative-name
                           temp-file
                           (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
         (list "tidy" (list local-file))))

(defun flymake-html-load ()
  (interactive)
  (when (and (not (null buffer-file-name)) (file-writable-p buffer-file-name))
    (set (make-local-variable 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks)
         '(("\\.html\\|\\.ctp\\|\\.ftl\\|\\.jsp\\|\\.php\\|\\.erb\\|\\.rhtml\\|\\.vue" flymake-html-init))
         )
    (set (make-local-variable 'flymake-err-line-patterns)
         ;; only validate missing html tags
         '(("line \\([0-9]+\\) column \\([0-9]+\\) - \\(Warning\\|Error\\): \\(missing <\/[a-z0-9A-Z]+>.*\\|discarding unexpected.*\\)" nil 1 2 4))
         )
    (flymake-mode t)))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'flymake-html-load)
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'flymake-html-load)
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook 'flymake-html-load)
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'flymake-html-load)
```

The trick is `tidy` will output some extra errors/warnings on modern HTML5 files. We use Elisp to ignore them.

I know there is `tidy-html5` but I'm too lazy to compile and install it.

Screenshot:

[image]

UPDATE:
 I tested https://github.com/TobiasZawada/html-check-frag which also works fine. There is only one difference. When you insert an open html tag without ending tag, my solution will highlight the open tag on the spot. For some reason, `html-check-frag` will highlight the last ending tag in the whole file. Maybe this is a bug of `html-check-frag`?

flymake:
[image]

html-check-frag:
[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all your effort answering my question. This is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe both tags should be highlighted, the div-tag and the closing body-tag. The div-tag is the non-closed tag and the body-tag is the closing tag which does not match the div-tag. Thanks for checking out html-check-frag by the way.

Answer (score 3):

web-mode maintainer here.
I've pushed a fix to use `web-mode-html-tag-unclosed-face` instead of `web-mode-html-tag-face` as long as the tag remains unclosed. This face can be customised (e.g. adding a red background to it)